# MS Release Management- The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I am getting the following error when i trigger a release from MS RM client. This error message is from Event Viewer of the target machine.

```
Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.: \r\n\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndGetAsyncMemoryStreamFromResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndDownloadString(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClient.EndGet(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.BaseDeploymentControllerServiceProxy.GetPackageFileInfos(String packageLocation)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.HttpPackageDownloader.CopyPackageAndUnpackIt(String packageSourceLocation, String filesDestinationLocation)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.CopyComponentFiles()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.DeployComponent()
```

From the deployment log, I can see file copying component is getting failed.

I am able to manually copy files from the RM server machine to a shared location in the target machine. The folder I have shared with the same user running the Deployment Agent and copying is working fine.

Please see the Deployment log screen below.
[image: Deployment Log screen]

I am expecting some positive responses from the experts.

Comment: I have the same issue and cant find the reason for this. Do you have any update on this issue?

Comment: For internal server error, it is always better to get the server logs. they would indicate what actually went wrong. You have pasted the deployer logs here. You can find the server logs at - C:\Windows\Temp\Microsoft\ReleaseManagment\12.0\Logs\ReleaseManagementServices.l‌​og on the server machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will occur in different scenarios. I have done two things to resolve it in my case.

1. The drop location I have changed to a shared location(UNC Path). Previously the option "Copy Build output to the server" was selected in the release template.
2. Opened the port 445 for TCP and UDP in the Azure.

Now there is no such error on my release, build has been released successfully...!